# how can I edit my current sublime text 2 theme?

Tags: sublimetext

I would like to update my current SB2 theme Sunburst so that the current line highlight is a little brighter but I'm not sure how to do this. I know the following code has to be added but I don't know how to access the theme files:

```
<key>lineHighlight</key>
<string>#hexcolor</string>
```

Can anyone advise on how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can use this online theme editor http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On Windows XP, they are in XML `.tmTheme` files in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Application Data\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default\
```

On Vista/7/8/10 it will be in:

```
C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default\
```

Comment: Results for `pwd` in OS X shows: `/Users/your_user_name/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default`.

Comment: you can use my visual theme editor to edit your sublime theme files: http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/

Comment: On windows 7 it will be under: `C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default\`

Comment: Ubuntu: `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default` (remember to escape spaces or to quote the whole name if you `cd` there)

Answer (score 11):

You can try out [Color Scheme Editor plugin for ST](https://github.com/bobef/ColorSchemeEditor-ST2) which will help you to edit the current theme that you're using. 
Even more, it will automatically show you what theme is being applied in your current position (that is real handy); you can then make the change in theme-file, save, and you will instantly see the result.

Comment: The link is dead and the user doesn't have an account on GitHub under this name anymore.